# HTML div to screenshot?

Tags: php, jquery, html, screenshot

I tried to google it, but without much success.

Here is my problem:
I have something like a drag-and-drop game in jQuery, where the user drags some items (div with img) to the droppable drawing area.

I need a screenshot of the users design so I can put all designs into a gallery page.

My problem is how to get the HTML code into a jpeg/png/gif/canvas/whatever.
Btw. I'm on a shared PHP hosting on the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Store each piece's location at all times in javascript, and then just submit that data and re-build the images/locations based on the passed javascript data.

Comment: i'm storing it already. however image would be much more elegant. this way i have a bunch of dom objects, and i have to resize them with zoom

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are describing is extremely complex to write with PHP - but there are services such as www.thumbshots.com or www.browsershots.com that do the same thing. This question has been asked similarly many times before here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=screenshots+with+php

Comment: I have seen those sites. Maybe I'm wrong, but that look to me like periodical bot capturing, at least thumbshots.com. I need something on-demand

Answer (score 1):

You want to build your game in canvas, which can then export itself out as a PNG file that you could then have submitted back to the server.

Comment: can i just put the DOM elements in a canvas, or do i have to rewrite the whole game?

Comment: HTML code cannot use a canvas to save as an image because it could be a privacy issue. This code can only be used in a chrome/firefox add-on.